# Cambiar carácter de Excel con Python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de cambiar un carácter por otro en Excel con Pandas pero ejecuto el código y no sucede nada el carácter no se cambia, alguien me puede decir que tengo mal o que me falta.

No me da ningún error, pero no funciona.

Gracias.

```
import pandas as pd

File = pd.ExcelFile('excel.xlsx')

df=File.parse('Hoja1')

df = df.replace('_',' ')

print(df)
```

Quiero cambiar el guion bajo  por un espacio el blanco.

Hola_no = Hola no

Comment: El caracter no cambien en donde? que hace replace?

Comment: @Maidagan el df me imprime el data frame en la consola, solo lo tengo para revisar desde de la consola y  no tener que abrir el archivo de Excel para ver si funciono

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que tu pregunta deja bastante que desear, no se si lo he entendido correctamente, pero lo que intuyo que quieres es quitar la barra baja de *Hola_no* y sustituirla por un espacio en blanco.

Si eso no te funciona, no le estarás pasando lo que espera la función `replace`

```
txt = "Hola_no"

txt = txt.replace("_", " ")

print(txt)
```

La respuesta es:

> Hola

Habría que mirar cual es realmente el valor de `df=File.parse('Hoja1')`

Comment: Correcto, eso el que quiero realizar pero lo quiero realizar un Excel a palabras que se encuentran dentro de un Excel

Comment: Entonces tendrás que darle formato al texto que recibes, ya que no te lo interpreta de la manera correcta. La verdad que me está costando mucho leer cada frase que pones, estaría bien si escribes más claro. Me lo he imaginado @gbianchi por eso he eliminado el comentario.

Comment: @HarlanEnciso basicamente, tu pregunta es: Quiero usar pandas para cambiar el texto que esta dentro de un excel... Eso, no esta escrito en ningun lado. Quiero leer el texto con pandas, cambiar algunos caracteres, y devolverlos a excel... Quiero cambiar "esto" por "esto" en todas las filas (o donde sea)... Esa es tu pregunta, y eso deberia estar todo escrito ahi. Esta respuesta es correcto a la poca informacion de la pregunta.

Comment: @gbianchi es correcto lo que dices.

Comment: @gbianchi la cuestión es que no quiero cambiar una palabra completa sino un solo carácter de esa palabra por otro carácter.

Comment: Entonces por favor, modifica tu pregunta para reflejar tu problema real. No importa que quieras cambiar, es lo mismo. @HarlanEnciso